# Importing file from path

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a python program that reads from a file 'point.dat' However, when I run the code, I received the error message below.

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'points.dat'

May I know what is missing? I tried replacing with the file path but that didn't work as well. any library i need to import in for this to work?

```
xy=0
xx=0
with open('points.dat') as f:
    for line in f:
        x,y=[float(p.strip()) for p in line.split(',')]
        xy+=x*y
        xx+=x*x

k=xy/xx

print('Equation of line y = {:.2f}x'.format(k))
x=input('Enter x coordinate or <ENTER> to end: ')
while x!='':
    y=float(input('Enter y coordinate: '))
    x=float(x)
    if(abs(x*k-y)<1e-2):
        print('('+str(x)+',',str(y)+') is on the fitted line')
    else:
        print('('+str(x)+',', str(y) + ') is not on the fitted line')
    x = input('Enter x coordinate or <ENTER> to end: ')
print('End Program')
```

Comment: Have you tried supplying `access mode`? That shouldn't be an issue as I see.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure the extension is correct for the file you are point to? Also have you tried an absolute file path?